# Mock AWS Cognito in Laravel tests

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit, amazon-cognito

I have feature tests that send requests to the api on behalf of a user to make sure the controllers behave appropriately. I previously used the Laravel's actingAs method, but now that I'm using Cognito the validation is made on AWS side.

Is there something that exists that could help me with this, or can someone share details about mocking the AWS Cognito logging in the tests?

Thank you

Comment: That is possible and i can fix that. But i need some code, to show how to do it.

Comment: AWS cognito is a different user provider so you should incoporate it as such in Laravel as described in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards) if you do this then you can continue using `actingAs` same as before